# CMake: Replace a literal citation mark with an escaped one

Tags: cmake

I have a string containing something like this:

```
Hello "there" happy face!
```

and I want to do a `string(REPLACE ...)` in CMake so that it becomes:

```
Hello \"there\" happy face!
```

How do I do this?

`string(REPLACE "\"" "\\"" TARGET "${SOURCE}")` does not work

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the answer to this question while writing it...

To get a literal `\` in the replace target we need to escape it not just once but twice: `\\\\`

Then to get a literal `"` we need to escape that as well `\"`.

So to replace a literal `\"` with an escaped one, we need: `\\\\\"`.

That is: `string(REPLACE "\"" "\\\\\"" TARGET "${SOURCE}")`